# What can $\log_e(x) + \log_e(1+x) =0$ be written as?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

The equation $\log_e(x) + \log_e(1+x) =0$ can be written as:

a) $x^2+x-e=0$

b) $x^2+x-1=0$

c) $x^2+x+1=0$

d) $x^2+xe-e=0$

I tried differentiating both sides, then it becomes $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{1+x}=0$, but I dont get any of the answers.

Comment: what is $$\log e x$$? should it be $$\log_{e} {x}$$

Comment: Yes - it's log x to the base e - sorry for the mistake

Comment: It looks to me like you're in the middle of an exam and are just posting the questions here in order to cheat.  That's not what we're here for.

Comment: Please disguise your question better so that no one can get a hint that you're in an exam if you are in an exam

Comment: Or actually, adding on to what @AmateurMathGuy said, if you are in an exam, just don’t post at all. You shouldn’t have any reason to disguise your question, unless you are *not* in an exam and you are being falsely accused of being in one, but we have our reasons of being suspicious. So if you are in an exam, well... all I can say is that what goes around, comes around...

Comment: You must swear an oath that you are not taking an exam, then never post anything looking like an exam.  These are the rules of this website.   It's on the internet but you must swear by these rules.

Comment: Your proctor needs to secure everybody's phone really

Comment: Why would you differentiate?

Comment: I never considered you might be in an exam. _If_ you were in an exam i am sorry i took the time to help

Answer (score 1):

then you will get $$\ln(x)+\ln(1+x)=\ln(1)$$ or $$x(x+1)=1$$
can you finish?

Comment: Well you are saying that $\ln(1) = 0$ because $e^0 = 1$ and I couldn’t agree more with you, but it just came across me that $e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0$ so... $e^{i\pi} = -1 \Leftrightarrow e^{2i\pi} = 1\Leftrightarrow 2i\pi = 0$?

Comment: i think $x$ is a real variable here

Comment: Hahaha. Perhaps my idea would be for another day, or perhaps another question of mine. But it’s a paradox anyway because if $2i\pi = 0$ then $i\pi = 0$ and therefore $e^0 + 1 = 1 + 1 = 2\neq 0$ so there you go. A bit like thinking $5 = -5$ because $5^2 = (-5)^2$.

Comment: @user477343 This solution can be done without eliminating the log from both sides. make the first line $ln(x)+ln(1+x)=0$ Using log properties the equation becomes $ln(x(1+x))=0$ and using the definition of ln we get $x(1+x)=e^{0}$ thus we get the result of the answer with no iffy eliminations.

Answer (score 1):

For $x>0,$

$$\ln (ex)=\ln (e)+\ln (x)=1+\ln (x) $$

and $$-\ln (x)=\ln \Bigl(\frac {1}{x}\Bigr) $$

the equation will be

$$\ln (x+1)=\ln \Bigl(\frac 1x\Bigr) $$

or

$$x+1=\frac 1x $$
and the answer is  $ x^2+x-1=0$

Comment: Use **\left( $\ldots$ \right)** for appropriate sizes of brackets. For example, instead of $(\dfrac 1x)$ you could generate $\left(\dfrac 1x\right)$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\log(A) + \log(B) = \log(AB)$
$$
\begin{align}
\log(x) + \log(1+x) &=0\\
\Rightarrow \log{\left( x(1+x)\right)} &=0 \\
\Rightarrow x(1+x) &= 1 \\
\Rightarrow x^2 + x -1 &=0
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Recall that $$\log_e x + \log_e(x+1) = \log_e\Big( x(x+1)\Big) = \log_e(x^2+x)$$ and that $$ \text{if } \log_e(x^2+x) = 0 \text{ then } x^2+x = e^0. $$